# No result for union by using getjdbctemplate()

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate

i am using a sqlQuery =

```
 "(SELECT  c1,c2 FROM doc1 WHERE docId= ? )
    UNION (SELECT c1,c2 FROM doc2WHERE docId= ? )"
 c1,c2 exists and are same type
```

i am using

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlQuery,new Object[]{docID,},
                    new RowMapper() {
                public DOC mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Doc doc = new DoC ();
                    doc.setVersion(rs.getInt(1));
                    return doc;
                }
            });
```

the statement does not get executed , it terminates without any error.

if i  do not use *UNION* and make as 2 seperate Queries , i am able access data, but that makes me to write one more `getJdbcTemplate().query().`

please suggest,

thanks in advance.

Comment: i even tried UNION ALL

Comment: First off all there is no space between `doc2` and `WHERE`, second you have to placeholders but a single element array in your `query` method.